# SAX Representation of Time Series

Tags: sql, time, visualization, series

To create a SAX representation of a Time Series you first need to calculate the PAA (piecewise aggregate approximation) of the data and then map the answers to a symbolic table. However before calculating the PAA you need to normalize the data.

I am normalizing the data but I do not know how to calculate the PAA afterwards. Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to use an example of PAA from this [Keogh's paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/79074/time_series_indexing.pdf) and illustrate the transform of the time series consisting of 8 points into 2 points using piece-wise aggregate approximation using R.

So, here is the data, and I sort of highlighted the four first and four last points (two pieces) whose values are going to be aggregated into a single value that represents a "piece":

```
// data
X = c(-1, -2, -1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0) 

// let's plot it
plot(X,type="l",lty=2,main="PAA example")
points(X[1:4],pch=16,lwd=5)
points(y=X[5:8],x=c(5:8),pch=17,lwd=5)
abline(v=c(1,4,5,8),lty=3,lwd=2)
```

[image]

Now, following the PAA procedure we compute mean values for each of four-points-length segments (i.e. we aggregate values of four points into a single point):

```
// compute the PAA value for the first segment
p1=mean(X[1:4])

segments(1,p1,4,p1,lwd=2,col="blue2",lty=3)
points(x=2.5,y=p1,col="blue2",pch=23,lwd=20)

// compute the PAAvalue for the second segment
p2=sum(X[5:8])/4

segments(5,p2,8,p2,lwd=2,col="darkorchid2",lty=3)
points(x=6.5,y=p2,col="darkorchid2",pch=23,lwd=20)
```

here we have these two PAA values shown at the plot:

[image]

Now lets transform the same eight points length time series into three PAA points. But here we run into an issue when 8/3 does not produce an integer so we need to add a fraction of the "belonging" to the adjacent segments point value to those segments. Here I show three segments of the same time series which need to be converted into PAA values:

```
plot(X,type="l",lty=2,main="PAA example #2")
points(X,pch=16,lwd=5)
abline(v=c(1,1+7/3,1+7/3*2,8),lty=3,lwd=2)
```

[image]

To perform the transform, I define a function which at first "explodes" the original time series into a matrix with the number of rows equal to the PAA size and the number of columns equal to the original time series length, whose rows values are the input time series values. Second, I "reshape" this matrix into the one whose number of columns equals PAA size and number of rows equals the input time series length. Finally, to get the PAA values, I compute the means of the matrix' columns.

Note that I use the `matlab` library for reshaping the matrix which represents the input time series:

```
library(matlab)
paa <- function(ts, npoints){
  len <- length(ts)
  if(len != npoints){
    if( (len %% npoints) == 0 ){
      res <- reshape(ts, len %/% npoints, npoints)
    }else{
      tmp <- matrix(rep(ts, npoints), byrow = T,nrow = npoints)
      res <- reshape(tmp, len, npoints)
    }

    matrix(colMeans(res), nrow=1, ncol=npoints)

  } else {
    ts
  }
}
```

Let's see these PAA values on the plot:

```
p3=paa(t(X),3)
segments(1,p3[1],1+7/3,p3[1],lwd=2,col="red")
points(x=1+7/3/2,y=p3[1],col="red",pch=23,lwd=20)
segments(1+7/3,p3[2],1+7/3*2,p3[2],lwd=2,col="red")
points(x=1+7/3+7/3/2,y=p3[2],col="red",pch=23,lwd=20)
segments(1+7/3*2,p3[3],8,p3[3],lwd=2,col="red")
points(x=1+7/3*2+7/3/2,y=p3[3],col="red",pch=23,lwd=20)
```

[image]

For production, I have implemented the discretization of time series via sliding window with Symbolic Aggregate approXimation (SAX) in Java. Here is my [library](https://github.com/jMotif/SAX) which implements the SAX transform and its parallelized version.

Specifically, Piece-wise Aggregate Approximation (PAA) is implemented in [this class](https://github.com/jMotif/SAX/blob/master/src/main/java/net/seninp/jmotif/sax/TSProcessor.java#L289)

Thanks!